# How to structure big Node.JS modules

Tags: node.js, project-structure, modules

I am working on a rather big Node.JS project with several thousand lines of code. It's not a homepage, but acts more like a configurable general purpose application server. As such it brings some parts which are useful in most projects I do.

The problem is that I easily lose overview in the core modules. So I did a bit of research and came up with an interesting structure based on C++ Header/Code file structures. I want to know if this structure is good in the long run (maintainability, testability, extensibility), how it can be improved and if there is already a (better) "standard" way of doing the structuring I did not find.

The structure has three kinds of files, where xxx is the module name and yyy is the method name.

- xxx.h.js: The "header" file, which contains the class and method declarations
- xxx.yyy.c.js: The "code" files, which contain one method each (and possibly local helper functions)
- index-xxx.js: The glue and main file for the module

I would like to structure all my sub-modules like this and then use a loading-mechanism to load all modules, namespace them and finally use them globally.

Here's an example:

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Does something in the core system",
    "author": "Marco Alka",
    "main": "index-foo.js"
}
```

```
// index-foo.js
'use strict';

// return class
module.exports = require('./foo.h.js');

// overwrite definitions with declarations
// this part can and most probably will be done generically by my module loader. I write it down for easier overview.
require('./src/foo.bar.c.js');
require('./src/foo.baz.c.js');
```

```
// foo.h.js
'use strict';

/**
 * Easy-to-read interface/class
 * No obstructive code in my way
 */
module.exports = class Foo {

  constructor() {}

  /**
   * Put comments here
   */
  bar() { throw 'Not Implemented'; }

  /**
   * More comments for methods
   * See how the method declarations+documentations nicely dominate the file?
   */
  baz() { throw 'Not Implemented'; }
}
```

```
// src/foo.bar.c.js
'use strict';

// include header
var h = require('../foo.h.js');

// implement method Foo::bar
h.prototype.bar = function () {

  console.log('Foo.bar');
}
```

```
// src/foo.baz.c.js
'use strict';

// include header
var h = require('../foo.h.js');

// implement method Foo::bar
h.prototype.baz = function () {

  console.log('Foo.baz');
}
```

Example on how to use the whole thing from within the root folder

```
'use strict';

// later on a module loader will be used which loads the folder as module instead of the index file directly
var F = require('./index-foo.js');

// make object
var foo = new F();

// call method
foo.bar();
```

Output in console: `Foo.bar\n`

Comment: The reason that your question didn't get much attention when you asked it  is because it is too broad.  Questions like "Am I right?" and "Is this a good approach?" seldom make good questions, because we don't know what your specific criteria is for "right" or "good," which means we have to write a very long answer to cover every positive or negative possibility.  Real questions have answers; I suggest you focus your question on a more specific problem.  Otherwise, the answer is "yes, if it meets your requirements."

Comment: See also [Are Design Review questions on-topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6502)

Comment: `The problem is that I easily lose overview in the core modules.` -- What does this sentence mean?

Comment: Incidentally, Googling your question title yielded a number of interesting results, including [this one](https://blog.redradix.com/an-architecture-for-complex-node-js-apps-with-dependency-injection/) which mentions Dependency Injection, the first thing I thought of when I saw your question.

Comment: My focus for this question is on how the files interact with each other. Is it a good idea to scatter the code? Is there a better way to divide my big code file into many smaller ones? Will the require-lines in the index-file cause more confusion later on than they bring merit? Google did not yield anything interesting when I searched for how to organize my module with ten thousand lines so that I do not have to constantly use search just to find a method (not the search term I used, but do you get what I am trying to do, now?)

Comment: How many methods are in your ten thousand lines of code?

Comment: About twenty public and private methods with additional helper functions.

Comment: If the IDE you're using doesn't already have a dropdown listing the methods in the module, make yourself a spreadsheet that lists the methods along with their (approximate) line number positions.  Or, break your module into smaller modules with less methods.  This isn't a difficult problem, nor is it a matter of best practice; you need to organize your code in a way that suits your work style.  By the way, ten thousand lines seems like a lot for a single module (though maybe not, in Javascript).

Comment: I do not think that would be a big improvement. I want to get rid of this one huge scrolling-monster by introducing smaller files with a more precisely categorized content. I am working a lot on the different modules and the different methods in them and keeping track of how they interact with what is getting more and more difficult. I often find myself scrolling for minutes until I find what I was really looking for. Having a small file whiich only contains code which belongs together seems to me like the best solution. Just the how is something I am not that sure about...

Comment: ten thousand lines is not that much when you have to implement many things, like type checks, async handling, logging,... and all the error management this produces together with high demands like ASVS security measures and the like :)

Comment: Perhaps this is merely an IDE problem or educational problem then.  In Intellij you can choose a method in a module from a list; this is true of many other IDEs as well.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11840760/102937

Comment: I am working with VS2013+NTVS. Selecting functions from a list is possible (just checked). But this does not feel clean. It's just a workaround in order to find functions and methods, but does not give any relation between them at all. It's like you put all your clothes onto one big pile and then use a giant sieve to find your socks. You don't do that at home, do you? You place them all neatly into your drawers separated by what purpose they serve. Well, at least I do that :)

Comment: Think the following: you get an error on your productive terminal which says `error: "value" not defined on line 3974:16`. What part is broken? Is it critical and you have to open an emergency and work on it immediately or is it a small thing which does not really concern anyone that much and which can wait until next week? You add a breakpoint and the debugger starts to wildly jump thousands of lines for and back. You have to always take a look where you are now and how the code path unfolds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a newbie and I'm pretty sure this is an opinion-based answer which is really outside the scope of the board.   With that, here's my practical experience:

- There are no implicitly bad ways to structure code, so long as the structure can be described simply.
- The only thing bad about poor code structure is lack of discipline: if you consistently follow the structure when developing, then you or anyone else editing your code should be able to discern the context quickly.
- Even if you are the only person on your development team (which is sounds like you are), use Git or some other kind of repository with good robust explanations for what you changed and why.

It's been my experience that code structures are not usually the culprits for making things difficult to manage.   It's logical architecture and documentation.   If you have a good logical architecture that clearly defines modularity of functionality and you document what you've done, it will be an investment that pays off.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Your answer is pretty vague, but it definitely confirms me in what I am doing. We are currently two people on the team working with TFS with no quality control or the like. So I really have to do anything I can to keep the codebase clean with a good overview, especially when it's very likely that I will have to introduce it to other people (or maybe even teams) later on. Also working with the code (debugging etc.) has to be efficient since we are such a small team